# Can't manage nil with Codable concept swift 4 while json parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

I want to parse some ***data with some null field***.And ***if the value of string is null than it should be replace with ""***(blank) likewise for all data types. If the value is getting nil than I want to set default value of variable. here in JSON I am getting value of brewery null.

***JSON For example***

```
{
    "name": "Endeavor",
    "abv": 8.9,
    "brewery": null,
    "style": "ipa"
}
```

I have created model class like this.

```
struct Beer: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var brewery: String?
    var style: String?
}
```

I want to decode given json to Beer class, ***So how can I Manage Nil with Default value??***

Answer (score 0):

The optional value inside model is perfectly fine.

At the time of parsing JSON you could:

1. Use Swift coalescing operator `??`

   `Brewery = someOptionalValue ?? ""`
2. Create your own category around optional:

   `extension Optional {
       func getOrElse<T>(defaultValue: T) -> T {
           if let value = self? {
               return value as T
           } else {
               return defaultValue
           }
       }
   }`

   and use it as `Brewery = someOptionalValue.getOrElse("")`
3. or you could simply use a ternary operator

**EDIT 1:** As per the comment

Modify the model as below and access `breweryComputed` instead of `brewery`

```
struct Beer: Codable {
var name: String?
var brewery: String?
var style: String?

var breweryComputed : String {
    get{
        return (self.brewery ?? "")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In swift 4 Codable will directly parse the json, So how can I?

Comment: @anshul-king : Did you try the answer I posted? Is it not working yet ?

Comment: @anshulking : yea, Swift 4 codable will directly parse the JSON. You can create a computed property with a modified getter to access `brewery` every time. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari in swift 4 if json key value is nil then Decodable will set it nil.